# Groovy: failure in loading an external library

Tags: groovy

I'm fairly new to Groovy and I'd need to execute a script which creates an Excel file using Apache POI.

```
@Grab( 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.9' )
import static org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle.*
import static org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook

new HSSFWorkbook().with { workbook ->
  def styles = [ LIGHT_BLUE, LIGHT_GREEN, LIGHT_ORANGE ].collect { color ->
    createCellStyle().with { style ->
      fillForegroundColor = color.index
      fillPattern = SOLID_FOREGROUND
      style
    }
  }
  createSheet( 'Output' ).with { sheet ->
    (0..4).each { rownum ->
      createRow( rownum ).with { row ->
        (0..4).each { colnum ->
          createCell( colnum ).with { cell ->
            setCellValue( "[$colnum,$rownum]" )
            cellStyle = styles[ ( ( rownum * 5 ) + colnum ) % styles.size() ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
    new File( '/tmp/test.xls' ).withOutputStream { os ->
      write( os )
    }
  }
}
```

The script fails with:

```
General error during conversion: Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.5!commons-codec.jar]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.5!commons-codec.jar]
```

What I've observed is that the ~/.groovy/grapes/commons-codec/commons-codec has been created with the following content:

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user1 user  6797 Aug  2  2016 ivy-1.5.xml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user1 user 10213 Aug  2  2016 ivy-1.5.xml.original
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user1 user   882 Oct 12 12:02 ivydata-1.5.properties
```

I'm not at all expert with groovy but I'd expect some jars to be there. I've tried deleting the folder "~/.groovy/grapes" however it didn't help.
Can you advise any fix?

Comment: What does your Groovy script look like? What dependencies you load using Grape?

Comment: I've updated the question with the script I'm using.

Comment: When I run your script I get the 1.5 jar in `~/.groovy/grapes/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars` directory. I don't have the test.xls file so it fails at that point. My xml file has a different timestamp than yours which indicates a different repo perhaps that what you are getting. Looking in my ivydata properties file looks like I am getting the artifact from jcenter. If you are using the default grape config, that comes after the local m2 repo. I'd perhaps clear the commons codec directory in ~/.m2/repository if you find it there. Perhaps it is corrupted.